# javascript grouping linked nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, d3.js, grouping

I have 2 lists - nodes and links... Now what I would want is the most efficient way to add all the **directly/indirectly** linked elements into different groups.... For eg, 0 is connected to 1 which is connected to 2 so nodes 0,1,2 become group 1.... node 3 is connected to 4 so it becomes group 2 and so on.... Thanks in advance for your help :) This is part of a d3 implementation am doing..

PS: These lists will easily be in tens of thousands of nodes and links.

```
"nodes":[
   {
      "id":0,
      "x":1509.9862,
      "y":-609.1013
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "x":1645.9578,
      "y":-85.06705
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "x":1948.1533,
      "y":-469.3646
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "x":348.1533,
      "y":-669.3646
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "x":1448.1533,
      "y":-1469.3646
   }
   ...
  ]

  "links":[
     {
        "from":0,
        "to":1
     },
     {
        "from":1,
        "to":2
     },
     {
        "from":3,
        "to":4
     }
     ...
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic UnionFind problem. The idea is to see each node as a set that has a pointer point to its father. Nodes with the same father are in the same group. So for your problem, we can create n sets at the beginning. And then iterate through the link to group everyone connected by the same link. The complexity is O(n), where n is the number of nodes.

```js
nodes = [{
    "id": 0,
    "x": 1509.9862,
    "y": -609.1013
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "x": 1645.9578,
    "y": -85.06705
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "x": 1948.1533,
    "y": -469.3646
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "x": 348.1533,
    "y": -669.3646
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "x": 1448.1533,
    "y": -1469.3646
  }
];

links = [{
    "from": 0,
    "to": 1
  },
  {
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2
  },
  {
    "from": 3,
    "to": 4
  }
];

// union-find is a data structure that can union two sets and check
// whether two element in the same set.

var father = {};

function group(nodes, links) {
  // create n set with each set has the node as its only element
  nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
    father[node.id] = node.id;
  });

  // union each set that has a link between them
  links.forEach(function(link, i) {
    union(link.from, link.to);
  });

  // for each unioned set, group nodes together
  var id = 1;
  var groupIdCnt = {};
  var groupIds = {};
  nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
    var f = find(node.id);
    if (typeof groupIds[f] === 'undefined') {
      groupIds[f] = id;
      groupIdCnt[id] = 1;
      id++;
    } else {
      groupIdCnt[groupIds[f]]++;
    }
  });

  var groups = {};
  nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
    var f = find(node.id);
    if (groupIdCnt[groupIds[f]] === 1) {
      node['group'] = 0;
    } else {
      node['group'] = groupIds[f];
    }

    if (typeof groups[node['group']] === 'undefined') {
      groups[node['group']] = [];
    }
    groups[node['group']].push(node);
  });

  return Object.values(groups);

}

// find father of each set
function find(node) {
  // if it is the root, return
  if (father[node] === node) {
    return node;
  }
  // if not, find the father and point to it
  father[node] = find(father[node]);
  return father[node];
}

// update the father of set which includes node1 to the father of set which includes node 2
function union(node1, node2) {
  father[find(node1)] = find(node2);
}

// O(n), since we visit each node once
var groups = group(nodes, links);
console.log(nodes);
console.log(groups);
```

Comment: This is excellent @junbang-huang... I needed something just a lil different... Where instead of joining the lists, if every node object can have a new attr "group":1,"group":2, etc. Not sure how easy or difficult it is

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: @ideate this should be returning what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) works perfectly... Will now stress test it for thousands of nodes & links...

Comment: let me know the result. I haven't tested it for that

Comment: Hi @junbang-huang, its performing pretty good. Just one quick question though... is there a way for any nodes that arent present inside links (basically arent linked) to be added to group 0? I am trying it bu keeps failing

Comment: good to hear! So, yes you can do that. Again, you can group them like I did for the first version. And the everyone has no link will be in a set of size one. You can count the size and then add those node into group zero. Let me know if you want me to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143450/discussion-between-ideate-and-junbang-huang).

Comment: I stumbled on another problem :/ looks like for larger number nodes and links... every group has atleast one node with group:0 .... I tried fixing it a bunch of times but couldnt find the solution... Wud u have a few mins to look at it?

Comment: @ideate what do you mean

Comment: check out the console for this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pdubey84/rrrrvxys/1/ ... Notice how it shows the nodes in group 0.... but if you look closely, nodes with id 1,2... have links (check them in links array)... So basically somehow few nodes become part of group 0 :`(

Comment: I tried modifying it a bunch of times, but couldnt find where the issue was

Comment: would greatly appreciate if you can point out the glitch... I have kind of come to a halt trying to figure tht out... :/

Comment: can you start a chatroom?

Comment: I just pinged... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/143450/discussion-between-ideate-and-junbang-huang

Answer (score 1):

In the solution below I am creating groups of `link`s that are, well, linked to each other. I do so by looping through all of the `from`/`to` combinations, and finding out if either has already been added to any of the accumulating groups of `link`s. If they have, then I just add (or re-add) both the `from` and `to` value to that group. If neither the `from` nor `to` value has yet been grouped, then I make a new group and add both the `from` and `to` values to it. Note that these "groups" are actually Javascript sets, a new ES6/ES2015 data type that makes it much easier to deal with "groups" of elements for which no duplicates are needed and/or allowed.

Once the groups/sets of links are established, I then simply add an attribute to each `node` that indicates which group of `link`s it is a part of.

Note that, for the sake of this demo code, I've simplified/de-cluttered some `node` values. I've also added some extra links, just to demonstrate some further cases that need handling.

```js
const groupNodes = (nodes, links) => {
  const groups = links.reduce((grps, {from, to}) => {
    if (!grps.some(grp => {
      if (grp.has(from) || grp.has(to)) return grp.add(from).add(to);
    })) grps.push(new Set([from, to]));
    return grps;
  }, []);
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    groups.forEach((grp, i) => { if (grp.has(node.id)) node.group = i; });
  });
  return nodes;
};



const nodes = [
  {
    "id":0,
    "x":0,
    "y":0
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "x":11,
    "y":-11
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "x":22,
    "y":-22
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "x":33,
    "y":-33
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "x":44,
    "y":-44
  },
  {
    "id":5,
    "x":55,
    "y":-55
  },
  {
    "id":6,
    "x":66,
    "y":-66
  }
];
const links = [
  {
    "from": 0,
    "to"  : 1
  },
  {
    "from": 1,
    "to"  : 2
  },
  {
    "from": 2,
    "to"  : 0
  },
  {
    "from": 3,
    "to"  : 4
  },
  {
    "from": 4,
    "to"  : 5
  },
  {
    "from": 6,
    "to"  : 0
  }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupNodes(nodes, links)));
```

Comment: It somewhat gives me what I want... But thanks a bunch for the solution

Answer (score 1):

This code spits out an object whose keys are the node id and whose values are a group id, not necessarily sequential.

```js
var obj = {
"links":[
     {
        "from":0,
        "to":1
     },
     {
        "from":1,
        "to":2
     },
     {
        "from":5,
        "to":4
     },
     {
        "from":3,
        "to":4
     }
  ]  
};

var groups = {};
var nextGrp = 1;

for (var i=0, l; l = obj.links[i]; i++) {
  if (groups[l.from]) {
    if (groups[l.to]) {
      if (groups[l.to] != groups[l.from]) {
        // the two items span two different groups which must now be joined into 1
        for (var j in groups) {
          if (groups[j] == groups[l.to]) {
            groups[j] = groups[l.from];
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      groups[l.to] = groups[l.from];
    }
  } else if (groups[l.to]) {
    groups[l.from] = groups[l.to];
  } else {
    groups[l.from] = nextGrp;
    groups[l.to] = nextGrp;
    nextGrp++;
  }
}

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution @james